# Artifact feed azure devops.Not sure how it meant to work

Tags: azure-devops

I have set up a feed on azure devops
I now have nuget.config in my solution with the packages sources configured with my feed.

Question

**Given that my mobile solution contains projects that will output nuget packages, why are those packages not appearing in my feed?**

When building the app in appcenter I was expecting all the dependencies and nugets to appear 
in the artifact feed automatically  but only 02  did?

do you have to have a pipeline to push packages to the feed?

Can just building a solution be enough for all the dependencies in the solution to be pushed
to the artifact feed? .Hope makes sense

I have looked at all microsoft docs and its' not clear!

Any suggestions how feeds are meant to work apart from pushing them yourself via either nuget push or a pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages don't get published to your feed unless you explicitly publish them to the feed. There's no mechanism that detects that you've created packages and automatically publishes them.

Use the NuGet task with the *push* option and you can choose the artifact feed to which your packages are published.